# Firebase rewrite to function doesn't work with custom domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase project with hosting and functions.

I have 2 hosting configs and a function.

I also have a custom domain, let's call it `example.com`.

After the setup, I have the following domains:

For the `web` target:

- `project-id.web.app`
- `project-id.firebaseapp.com`
- `example.com` redirect to `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com`

For the `app` target:

- `project-id-app.web.app`
- `project-id-app.firebaseapp.com`
- `app.example.com`

My problem is with the `app` target. I have a rewrite to a firebase function and the rewrite only works for the `web.app` and  `firebaseapp.com` domains, but not for the `app.example.com` custom domain.

- `project-id-app.web.app/function1` executes the function
- `project-id-app.firebaseapp.com/function1` executes the function
- `app.example.com/function1` does a rewrite to `index.html`

Where might my oversight be?

My `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "web",
      "public": "web/dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "app",
      "public": "app/dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/function1",
          "function": {
            "functionId": "function1",
            "region": "europe-west1"
          }
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html",
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```